# SUM of count column in SPARQL

Tags: count, sum, sparql

Hi I am new to SPARQL and need help with it.. I have written a query which GROUP_CONCAT my images and then I did a count on my image fields which yields the result as shown below

[image]

What I want now is SUM of imageCount field something as shown in fig below.. in this example total will be 6

[image]

```
SELECT ?id  
       (GROUP_CONCAT(?images; separator=";") as ?images) 
       (count( ?images) as ?imageCount )   
{
  GRAPH <virtual://sample> {
     ....
    ....

  }
      GROUP BY ?id
      LIMIT 10
```

Any help on this!! Thanks

Comment: I guess you need two sub queries for this. But even then you'd get the sum in each row because it will be the cartesian: `SELECT ?id ?images ?imageCount ?totalCount { {SELECT  (count(distinct ?images) as ?totalCount) { ... } } {SELECT ?id  (GROUP_CONCAT(?images; separator=";") as ?images) (count( ?images) as ?imageCount )   { ... } GROUP BY ?id
      LIMIT 10 }}` - maybe this works, maybe not. As usual untested because not sample data

Comment: Thanks for the response but it didn't work..Returns totalCount column with zero's.. Sorry couldn't upload sample data due to official restrictions... if you can help using any sample data that will be great..@AKSW

Comment: Another approach is to use a 'fictive key' (e.g. an unique value for the key var used in GROUP BY) into which to accumulate the totals. That way, you will end up with an additional `row` in the result with the desired aggregares computed. e.g.:
`select ?key (group_concat(...) as ?images) (count(?image) as ?count) where {  // the same block as from your query
{} UNION {bind("the row with totals" as ?totalsKey)} Bind(coalesce(?totalsKey, ?id) as ?key) Group by ?key`

Comment: @DamyanOgnyanov thanks for the response.. Want to confirm if you have tested it because for me new field sum value is coming zero!!!

Answer (score 0):

@fasalshah comments are limited in length so posting the relevant data as an answer

Yes, using following sample data:

```
insert data {
    <id:1> <id:image> "aq.png" ; <id:select> 1 .
    <id:2> <id:image> "a.png", "ab.png" ; <id:select> 1 .
    <id:3> <id:image> "qw.png" ; <id:select> 1 .
    <id:4> <id:image> "d1.png", "d2.png" ; <id:select> 1 .
    <id:5> <id:image> "x.png", "y.png" ; <id:select> 2 .
}
```

and following query:

```
select ?key (group_concat(?image;separator=";") as ?list) (count(*) as ?count) where { 
    ?id <id:image> ?image .
    ?id <id:select> 1 .
    {
    } union {
        bind("this row accumulates everything" as ?totals)
    }
    bind (coalesce(?totals, ?id) as ?key)
} group by ?key
```